# Authorizations for editing and (re)processing IDocs

Tags: authorization, idoc

I'm looking into the risk of unauthorized transactions through access to editing existing IDocs and reprocessing them.

In below scenarios, the following characteristics are applicable:

- User Y belongs to the finance department and has access to financial
  transactions in SAP.
- User Y has created the IDOC (related to financial transaction).
- User X belongs to the HR department and has NO access to financial transcations in SAP.
- User X has T-code level access to changing IDOCS.

**My question is, which of these scenarios is the correct one and what is the technical reasoning behind it?**

1. User X can edit an existing IDOC and reprocess it **successfully** because the IDOC/system checks the authorization of the IDOC creator (in this case: User Y).
2. User X can edit an existing IDOC and reprocess it **successfully** because the IDOC is in the queue and does not check for additional authorization.
3. User X can edit an existing IDOC but can **NOT** reprocess it because the IDOC/system checks the authorization of the IDOC changer (in this case: User X).

Answer (score 0):

You can create authorization object for IDOC message type, so user can not edit or send unauthorized message type. Otherwise user can 1,2 or 3. Details are here: http://sambitsapbasis.blogspot.com.tr/2009/08/special-authorization-object-for-idoc.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming User X created **outbound** IDoc and User Y received this **inbound** IDoc, the following endings will be real for your scenarios:

1. False
2. False
3. True

You have to get it clearly: sender has nothing to do with processor of the IDoc, **only processor matters**. SAP even [recommends](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/48/966d9c0eec3987e10000000a421937/content.htm) to cut sender's authorizations to minimum and process IDocs collectively in background in order to eliminate need for granting additional authorizations.

Generally, IDocs authorizations model is run around [these objects](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_di46c2/helpdata/EN/c7/1d4b6e5733d1118b3f0060b03ca329/content.htm), the most important from which are `S_IDOCMONI` and `S_IDOCCTRL`, and the general rule is:

> if user has authorization to disply IDocs (which is controlled by
>   `S_IDOCMONI`), he also able to send it.

If you want to restrict certain IDoc types for viewing and processing in BD87, you have to implement SAP note [1269516](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1269516).